# LINQ and the Enumerable.Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>) overload method

Tags: c#, linq

I have a question about a tricky trouble in LINQ (tricky almost for me!).

It's possible to write the following linqQuery

```
string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

var linqQuery= digits.Where((digit, index) => digit.Length < index);
```

which make use of `Enumerable.Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>)` Enumerable overload method, using the query syntax

```
var linqQuery = from ...
                where ...
                select ...;
```

?

The method `Enumerable.Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>)` use the `Int32` parameter as the index of the source element, and I wonder if this method can be inferred from a query syntax rather the other Enumberable overloaded method `Enumerable.Where<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)`.

Here the MSDN references

[Enumerable.Where method without Int32 parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)

[Enumerable.Where method with Int32 parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not possible. Query-syntax only supports a subset of the available operations. Nothing in query-syntax will compile down to that overload of `Where`.

What you have is perfectly fine. Here are some query-syntax ideas that will let you compose such an operation though:

```
var linqQuery = from d in digits.Where((digit, index) => digit.Length < index)
                // You can do more stuff here if you like
                select d;
```

Also consider projecting to a type that contains the index first (the `Select` overload that will help you do this has the same issue, unfortunately) and then perform the filter and other downstream operations in query-syntax:

```
var linqQuery = from tuple in digits.Select((digit, index) =>
                               new { Digit = digit, Index = index })
                where tuple.Digit.Length < tuple.Index
                // You can do more stuff here if you like
                select tuple.Digit;
```

Also consider [moreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)'s `SmartEnumerable`, which spares you the trouble of projecting to the tuple:

```
var linqQuery = from tuple in digits.AsSmartEnumerable()
                where tuple.Value.Length < tuple.Index
                // You can do more stuff here if you like
                select tuple.Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to invoke that overload of `Where()` (or the similar overload of `Select()`) using the query syntax.

From §7.16.2.4 of the C# 4.0 spec:

> A query expression with a `where` clause
>
> ```
> from x in e
> where f
> …
> ```
>
> is translated into
>
> ```
> from x in ( e ) . Where ( x => f )
> …
> ```